# Cloud Build - Errors exporting custom image to Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-build

I've never used Cloud Build. Referencing this guide: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/export-image and I've tried all the listed methods.

With different methods, it triggers different errors.

**When using the cloud console method, the error as followed:**
`Validation of network "projects/product-id/global/networks/default" failed: googleapi: Error 404: The resource 'projects/project-id/global/networks/default' was not found, notFound ERROR ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/compute-image-tools/gce_vm_image_export:release" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1`

I have deleted the default network. I have tried creating new VPC, setting the region and zone, and specifying the region and zone and experimenting with different regions but none work.

**When using the Google Cloud CLI method, the error as followed:**
`ERROR: (gcloud.compute.images.export) FAILED_PRECONDITION: generic::failed_precondition: due to quota restrictions, cannot run builds in this region`

I do not understand how the regions restriction work in this case. **Does it refer to the source or the destination?** I checked the regions https://cloud.google.com/build/quotas and the region that I want to export the image from and import to is within the allowed regions.

I checked the quota limits but not sure which service export custom image falls into. This is the quota and for the rest of the list is 0:
[image]

**My questions:**

- If is due to the quota limits, are there other way to export image to GCS?
- Which item from the list should I request to increase the quota?
- The regions restriction is referred to the source or destination? In this case, is it the VPC the VM is in or the GCS bucket location?

Comment: check this [document](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/export-image) alternative ways to export an image to Google Cloud Storage.Also have a look at this [link1](https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Developer-Tools/Google-Cloud-Build-throwing-quota-error/m-p/609957#M1167) & [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73497493/18265638)

Comment: @SathiAiswarya I believe my post contains information suggesting that the solutions provided in your reference links are not applicable.

Comment: check your image you’re trying to export if it has has a size of 1TB.  Cloud build has a known limitation which is the maximum timeout value permitted, the max value that can be applied to a build  is 24 hours. This might pose a problem for really large Images. In line with that, you can try running the [command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/images/export)
`gcloud beta compute images export --image=source-image --destination-uri=gs://bucket/image-name.vdi --export-format=vdi --docker-image-tag=latest --timeout=24h`. Also in which region your storage bucket located in

Comment: @SathiAiswarya image size is smaller than 1TB.

Comment: As you mentioned you are using vpc are you aware of this [Limitations and restrictions](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/export-image#limitations_and_restrictions)

Comment: @SathiAiswarya Not using VPC service controls. Export within the same project.

Comment: Seems like your issue needs to be inspected at project level and in-depth analysis is required to check the route cause. I recommend to contact [Google 
Support](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub)

Answer (score 0):

If you delete the default VPC, which is a good practice, you can specify the network and subnetwork on the `gcloud` command as parameters.

```bash
PROJECT="my-project"
IMAGE_NAME="source-image"
BUCKET_NAME="destination-bucket"
REGION="europe-west1"
NETWORK="projects/${PROJECT}/global/networks/my-network"
SUBNET="projects/${PROJECT}/regions/${REGION}/subnetworks/my-subnet"
URI="gs://${BUCKET_NAME}/exported-image.vmdk"

gcloud compute images export --destination-uri $URI --image $IMAGE_NAME --project $PROJECT --network $NETWORK --subnet $SUBNET
```

Source: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/images/export#--network

Comment: Thanks. As stated in the post, tried this method and it doesn't work.

Comment: The error says `cannot run builds in this region`. Which region are you trying to use?